# Probability with cups and plates

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have some trouble solving the next problem:

There are 6 pairs of cups and plates (i.e. 6 cups and 6 plates). 2 of them are blue, another 2 pairs are red and the last 2 pairs are white. Each cup is place over a plate randomly. What's the probability that non of the plates and cups have the same color?

My attempt:
For each pair of plates and cups there are $6^2 = 36$ possible combinations. And there are $6^2 - (2)(6) = 24$ possible distinct combinations for each pair.
So the probability of a pair been different is $P(U) = \frac{24}{36} = \frac{2}{3}$, where $U$ is the set of all distinct combinations for a single pair.
Finally the probability that the six pairs are distinct is $\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^6$ since each pair is independent of the rest.
However I'm not sure if my solution is correct or even my reasoning. Any help would be greatly helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Probability that a particular saucer has a marching cup is 2/6. But the probability that if they match, so does the other pair of the same colour, is smaller, only 1/5. This is because there is only 1 cup of the right colour left of the 5 remaining cups. The pairs are not actually independent.

Comment: @Peter so the probability that all pairs have the same color would be $(2/6)(1/5)(1/2)(1/3)(1)(1)$?

Comment: @ChavaEscobedo:  that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just multiply the factor $\frac 23$ together because the events are not independent.

Let's start with the blue plates.  The chance they both get white cups is $\frac 26 \cdot \frac 15=\frac 1{15}$.  Similarly, the chance they both get red cups is $\frac 1{15}$.  The chance they get one red and one white is $2 \cdot \frac 26 \cdot \frac 25= \frac 4{15}$. This checks, because the chance they get both blue is $\frac 1{15}$ and the chance they get two colors including blue is $2 \cdot \frac 4{15}$, for a total probability of all the possibilities of $1$

Assuming they both get white, the chance of success is $\frac 24 \cdot \frac 13 =\frac 16$ because both red plates have to get blue ones.  This gives $\frac 1{90}$ chance of success and we get another $\frac 1{90}$ from them getting both red.

Assuming they get a red and a white, we need the reds to get a white and a blue, which happens with probabilty $2\cdot \frac 14 \cdot \frac 23=\frac 13,$ giving a contribution to the success probability of $\frac 13 \cdot \frac 4{15}=\frac 4{45}$

The overall chance of success if $\frac 1{90}+\frac 1{90}+\frac 4{45}=\frac 19$